# Variance of parameter estimators in terms of $\ n$ observations in a linear time series model

Tags: regression, time-series, variance, estimation, linear-model

Let $\ X_t = b_1 + b_2.t + e_t$ be a linear model, where $\mathbb{E}(e_t)$ = 0, $\ var(e_t)$ = $\sigma_e^2$, and $\ cov(e_i,e_j)$ = 0 for all $\ i \neq j$.

I have derived the equations for the estimated  values of $\ b_1$ and $\ b_2$, respectively, $\hat{b}_1$ and $\hat{b}_2$ as:

$\hat{b}_1 = \overline{x}_t  - \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(x_t - \overline{x}_t).t}{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(\overline{t} - t).t}.t$

$\hat{b}_2 =\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(x_t - \overline{x}_t).t}{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(\overline{t} - t).t}$

where $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{t}$ are, respectively, the mean of the $\ x_t$ and $\ t$.

I have, however, to prove that:

$\ var(b_1) = \frac{2(2n+1)}{n(n-1)} \sigma_e^2$ and 
$\ var(b_2) = \frac{12}{n(n^2-1)}\sigma_e^2$

I know that I can write $ var(b_1) = \mathbb{E}[(b_1 -\mathbb{E}(b_1)]^2= \mathbb{E}(b_1^2) - \mathbb{E}(b)^2  $.

> Can I say then that $\ \ var(b_1) =var(\hat{b}_1) = \mathbb{E}[(\hat{b}_1 -\mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1)]^2= \mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1^2) - \mathbb{E}(\hat{b})^2  $.

Calling everything to the right of minus sign in the equation $\hat{b}_1$ as $\ m$, I thought of trying to work the algebra for $\mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1^2)$ and $\mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1)^2$ but got lost in my computation.

Plus, I don't know what to do with given $\ covariance$. I have a feeling at one point - to which I haven't gotten yet - I'll have to use it.

> How can I start from my estimated values and reach an equation for their respective variances?

Any help, hint, or direction to follow will be valuable.

---

Tried to go down this road here - but I wonder if there's any other way that doesn't involve so much algebra; hence; less prone to error.

$\mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1^2) = \mathbb{E}[(\overline{x}_t  - \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(x_t - \overline{x}_t).t}{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(\overline{t} - t).t}.t)^2]$ and

$\mathbb{E}(\hat{b}_1)^2 = (\mathbb{E}[(\overline{x}_t  - \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(x_t - \overline{x}_t).t}{\sum_{t=1}^{\ n}(\overline{t} - t).t}.t)])^2$